# Python: strptime() format-timezone field not working as expected

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm trying to parse a given string of custom format date into epoch time with the following code:

```
time_tuple = time.strptime('Tue Dec 05 13:01:48 PST 2017', '%a %b %d %X %Z %Y')
time_epoch = time.mktime(time_tuple)
```

The given date format is as shown in the code. The problem I'm facing is when the code is compile I keep getting error saying:

```
 ValueError: time data 'Tue Dec 05 13:01:48 PST 2017' does not match format '%a %b %d %X %Z %Y'
```

From what I can see, the format seems to be exactly as specified according to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

What seem's to be wrong?

Edit: 
I have tried using datetime instead of time as well, but didn't work

```
time_tuple = datetime.strptime('Tue Dec 05 13:01:48 PST 2017', '%a %b %d %X %Z %Y')
```

Based on the comments below, it seems like the timezone field(%Z) is causing the problem. It seems like that field is based on the timezone the code is ran, and not the timezone the input string gives.

Comment: It is locale-dependent, so maybe you are using a non-English locale which means the English abbreviations are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a different time zone than those described in the docs, however, if you change the time zone, you can try this:

```
import time
time_tuple = time.strptime('Tue Dec 05 13:01:48 EST 2017', '%a %b %d %X %Z %Y')
time_epoch = time.mktime(time_tuple)
```

Comment: But `time_tuple = time.strptime('Tue Dec 05 13:01:48 EST 2017', '%a %b %d %X %Z %Y')` throws the exception. I can reproduce it locally.

Comment: Very odd, I ran this using both Python2 and Python3 and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm not sure even sure where to start on this one. What version of Python 3? But for sure: `ValueError: time data 'Tue Dec 05 13:01:48 EST 2017' does not match format '%a %b %d %X %Z %Y'`

Comment: @roganjosh Python version 3.6.2

Comment: Ok, I'm on 3.6.3 and in Spyder, Windows 7. I wonder if that helps us track down the issue.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the timezone %Z argument. I am running into the same issue. Based on the docs, it seems like this should work. I'm running Windows 10, Python 3.6.0.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4.7, and tried it on Eclipse (Pydev), macOS 0.12.6 , fails with the same error.

Comment: @drumhellerb and based on that, I changed 'EST' to 'GMT' (I'm based in UK) and it doesn't throw an error. That's not how I interpret the way it should work from the docs.

Comment: @Ajax1234 What happens if you change your own example from 'EST' to 'GMT'?

Comment: @roganjosh It works for me with 'GMT' and 'UTC', but not 'EST' or 'PST'.

Comment: @roganjosh Ok this is weird, I changed it to UTC and GMT, both works. So this depends on the location the code is ran?

Comment: @roganjosh It still works when I changed the time zone to GMT. (I am based in the U.S in the EST, which may explain why EST works for me)

Comment: @Boku it seems so and I'd be inclined to say it's a bug but maybe I'm missing something fundamental here. It doesn't seem reasonable that it should behave differently based on your local timezone.

Comment: @roganjosh Yup, definitely seems not right, as that field is suppose to allow you to specific the timezone of the given datetime, and not your own timezone.

Comment: @roganjosh it is indeed odd, as it fails when I use `PST` for the timezone but works when using `EST`.

Comment: @Boku I'm going to bed now. Started writing a question about this but it doesn't make sense to build on/reference an unanswered question. It might be worth re-wording the title and some of the body based on what is discussed here. I haven't found a dupe myself and it's an interesting topic.

Comment: @Boku and I'm thinking cloud-based issues. Servers can be based in any country, so does it go by the locality of the server?

Comment: @roganjosh That could very well be true